# Problem when importing js-cookies in Main.js

Tags: vue.js, js-cookie

I'm trying import [js-cookies](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) in my main.js

> Main.js

```
import * as Cookies from "js-cookie";
Vue.use(Cookies)
```

> Using in component

```
 this.$Cookies.set('name', data.user, { secure: true });
```

> Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

what is the problem?
I have tried a thousand ways and it still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vue.use(name)` is used to install a vue plugin. The package will need an install method that receives a vue instance.

**#1**
You can use the cookies packages without a plugin importing the module in the component

```
<script>
import  Cookies from 'js-cookie';
export default {
  methods: {
    addCookie() {
      console.log('adding the cookie');
      Cookies.set('chocolate', 'chookies');
      console.log(Cookies.get());
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**#2** you can add a VUE plugin and set a Cookies prototype function to the Cookies module.
(Prototype vue functions will be available for components, it's standard to prefix them with $).

*src/CookiesPlugin.js*

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const CookiesPlugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.$Cookies = Cookies;
  }
};

export default CookiesPlugin;
```

*src/main.js*

```
import CookiesPlugin from './CookiesPlugin';
Vue.use(CookiesPlugin);
```

*In the component*

```
this.$Cookies.set('chocolate', 'chookies');
console.log(this.$Cookies.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a NOT Vue (Vanilla JS library) library and you are trying to use it as a Vue resource.

[Try using this one instead](https://github.com/cmp-cc/vue-cookies#readme)